# How do I make a local file public for use on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I have built a Dash app which I am attempting to deploy through Heroku.

The app depends on a csv which is stored locally on my machine.  When I run the app locally, it runs perfectly.  However, when I attempt to deploy the app through Heroku, I get an application error ; the log shows an error that it can't find that csv file.

I am sure that the csv file is spelled correctly and the path is correct (after all, the same fild path runs locally with no problem).  However I am getting this error:

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'/Users/adam/Desktop/abc.csv' does not exist: b'/Users/adam/Desktop/abc.csv'
```

How do I make this file available to heroku?

Comment: Your web backend will never be able to load data directly from your hard drive. The only reason it worked in development is that your server runs on the same machine as your client. You'll have to rewrite your application to allow users to upload data and then process it server-side.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggest your are hard coding the path to your code and using your local path, you have to use relative paths or a better way to detect the path, on Heroku the app path is `/app`